# Play store throwing error while uploading release build related to targets API level

Tags: android, ionic4

I have a Ionic 4 Application . When i upload the release apk on play store i am getting below mentioned error

**Your app currently targets API level 23 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure that it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26.**

**This is in my build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
        defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String
        defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
        defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
        defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**I have added these two lines in config.xml**

```
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

**This is my project info**

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\amana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)

Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Cordova Platforms     : not available

Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\amana\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)

NodeJS            : v8.11.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)

npm               : 6.9.1-next.0

OS                : Windows 10

Comment: Try using minSdkVersion,targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion.  You may need to check the build.gradle of your module to see against what property is "defaultTargetSdkVersion" being set.

Comment: I did not get you. You are talking about which module

Comment: You would have one app level gradle and a module level gradle . Could  you let me know the module level gradle?